# Resize textarea based on lines of text that comes from php/mysql variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I dont need it to resize automatically as you type, I just need it to be the correct size when the page loads
the variable is `$row['text'];`

```
<textarea style="width:630px;"><? echo $row['text'];  ?></textarea>
```

so  when the page loads, the textarea will display the value of that text.
I am trying to have it where it counts how many lines and sets the height of the text area based on that

Comment: Where's the code where it counts the lines?

Comment: @PedroL. no. Daedalus: not sure how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu can use a jquery plugin:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize

Or you can use CSS set the width and height to auto

Answer (score 1):

```
function set_height($str) {
  $ary = explode("\n", $str);
  $style = '';
  if(is_array($ary) && count($ary)>1) {
    $height = 18 * count($ary);
    $style=' style="height:'.$height.'px; width:630px;" ';
  }
  return $style;
}
```

the textarea

```
<textarea <?=set_height($row['text']);?> ><? echo $row['text'];?></textarea>
```

Comment: this is good but what if its a string with a return break /n then it caused it to read everything as 1 line ... thats the issue Im having with it.its good though thanks sel

Answer (score 1):

Jquery autoresize is the best option. The only other option that I can see being viable is using the text "rows" and "cols" attributes. Measure the amount of cols that would be equal to about 630px, about 32 (based on 630/20   20 is the average character width). You would then just need to know how many rows you need which is a much easier equation.

```
//Divide the width by the height to get the number of rows required, then round up with
//math.ceil to get a rounded number. (1.01 rows would still need to be 2 rows)

$num_rows = math.ceil(32 / strlen($rows['text']));
<textarea rows="<? echo $num_rows ?>" cols="32"><? echo $row['text'];  ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the height equal to the number of characters, like this... also i add respensive option

```
<?php 
function set_px_height($var) {
  $px = strlen($var);
  $style = '';
    $height = $px;
    if (!ismovil()){
        $height = $height / 4;
    }else{
        $height = $height * 0.80;
    }
    if ($height < 40){
        $height = 50;
    }
    $style=' style="height:'.$height.'px;"';
  return $style;
}

function ismovil(){
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4))){
     return true ;
    }
}?>
```

like this on textarea

```
<textarea <?=set_px_height($row['text']);?> ><? echo $row['text'];?></textarea>
```